# Turn on the device automatically

Tags: android

I want to develop an application that has auto-power on when the device is off.

There is a way to set your device to automatic power on? like a scheduled task?

Comment: No there is no way due to obvious security reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I want to develop an application that has auto-power on when the device is off."

Answer: This is impossible. You can't run code on a device which is turned Off.

If it would be possible, every anti-theft App would have something like that to track the phone.